# How to connect the elements with each other by a line Angular

Tags: angular, d3.js, cytoscape.js

How to connect the elements with a line like in the picture? When you click on one circle and then another, a line should be drawn. Maybe there is a library for this task, I've searched but haven't found anything useful. Angular.[image]

**Update**

The size of the screen should also change the line. I was also thinking of applying libraries such as d3 and cytoscape, as they seem to allow for drawing such lines. Maybe someone has some examples?

Comment: I think it should be possible: on first click you get reference to circle element, on second click you get reference to te second circle and then create a canvas/svg with boundaries reaching those circles, then you can draw a line between coordinates (including shift on X and Y axis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for me: [LeaderLine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leader-line)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GoJs](https://gojs.net/latest/index.html).

The GoJs is Compatible with angular. ([Document](https://gojs.net/latest/intro/angular.html))

This sample is similar to your needs: [sample one](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/draggablePorts.html), [sample two](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/treeMapper.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can make this stuff with svg. since its only a few lines and circles. I stitch a small example together here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ovhbww
Its basically use svg to draw things. Svg is create cause you can add events and also animation if you feel like it. With fairly simple code. What i put in the link is more of inspiration of how you could do it. Not so much that its the greatest piece of code :)